# My content area background image is showing up outside of the div in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

The style-sheet div in question is:

```css
#leftColumn {
    float: left; 
    width: 650px; 
    position: relative; 
    text-align:left;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/contentBg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The site isn't live yet but you can see what is happening on the page at http://www.downtowndefencelawyers.ca/index.php.  It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but nothing that I have tried has worked in IE.  Sorry if this is a basic fix but I seem to need help...  :)

Comment: Mind providing a screenshot? On a Mac here and I don't feel like corrupting it with IE :)

Comment: just tried in ie8 on my vm and it looks okay?

Comment: Hey thanks for quick replies - I am using IE9 but I looked at it in IE8 and IE7 and see the same issue.  At the bottom of the page just before the copyright footer info there is a small strip of the main content div background.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the bottom image display property?  display: block, display: inline-block, or display: inline?   I'm not sure which one is the default for an image.

Comment: Oh I am new here.  Sorry. I posted an answer instead of a reply.  LOL This was supposed to be a reply question!! My bad!

Comment: Yep, display: block to bottom img resolves the problem. Also page is run under Quirks mode, most probably because of first lines with comments in html source.

Comment: Hi - I tried setting the display property to both the div containing the background image as well as the image that is at the bottom of the content as suggested but no change.  I moved the comments you mentioned further into the page to be below the DOCTYPE declaration as well just in case that helps?